# Activate class="active" for archives.html in pelican

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jinja2, pelican

I am trying to setup my own theme in pelican and facing a problem how to get the `class="active"` set if one loads the archives page. Here is what I have so far:

```
{% if DISPLAY_PAGES_ON_MENU -%}
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  {% for pg in PAGES %}
    <li {% if pg == page %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ pg.url }}">{{ pg.title }} {{SITEURL}}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
  <li {% if url == "/archives.html" %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/archives.html">Archives</a></li>
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

This snippet works so far for the pg-loop. But I cannot figure out who to set the class to active when visiting archives.html. Does someone know how this can be done?

Also, since I am new to Jinja2 and pelican, I haven't found a documentation, which variables are available for use.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general tactic that I have used in the past is to print out `page_name` by putting it somewhere in the base.html template:

```
{{page_name}}
```

Then, I use an if statement based on the `page_name` that was displayed.

```
{% if page_name = "Archive" %} X {% endif %}
```

Also, there is reasonably useful documentation here: http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.5.0/themes.html#templates-and-variables

Comment: I actually had to use `{% if page_name == "archives" %}class="active"{% endif %}` and I didn't need the `{{page_name}}` in the base template...

Comment: Yes, putting `{{page_name}}` in the base template, is temporary, and only for identifying what the `page_name` actually is so that you can create your logic. Glad it worked for you.